# How to Stop Server Crash when Client Crashed internally (TCP/IP Socket)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, server, client

Description about the problem.

Currently I am developing server - multiple clients (over 3000 clients) application in csharp. Server and clients exchange messages. The problem is that server get crashed if any of the client crashes for the internal reason. The internal reason can include all sort of specific problem of client computer. For example, they can be the lost internet connection, the computer crash, power failure, etc.

As the server functions to deliver the real time information, if the server crashes, then entire operation stops. This is nightmare for server because we can not predict which client will crash.

The main code causing the server crashes is below:

```
    public bool Send(byte[] buffer)
    {
        if (m_Socket == null)
        {
            return (false);
        }


        try
        {
            mSocket.Send(buffer);

            return (true);
        }
        catch(System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
        {
            mSocket = null;
            return (false);
        }

        return (false);
    }
```

I think there were few answers to the similar problem from my research. However often the answers point out the use of Keep alive packets.

I think many answer in this website indicates that detecting the half open connection (dropped connection) is almost impossible without using keep alive packet from client side.

In our application, we do not prefer to use Keep alive packet or message because the server and client communicate in milliseconds. Receiving keep alive packet or message from over 3000 clients every seconds does not seems friendly for resource management point of view for server. So we prefer to have rather a good error management. If the client computer is crashed, then we just want to ignore. I am not sure whether this can make the running server unstable ?

Anyway, I came up with few ideas with below options. It was the suggestions from other coders most of time on the net. So the question is Which option might be the best to safely catch the Socket.Send() failure error and not disturbing the operation of the server?

1. Using simple try catch statement. Will this offer the 100% secure fail safe operation for this problem ? From my experience, sometimes, it works but sometimes it does not work.

   ```
   try
   {
       mSocket.Send(buffer);

       return (true);
   }
   catch(System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
   {
       mSocket = null;
       return (false);
   }
   ```
2. Use of while(true) loop. Someone mentioned that while(true) loop might be the safe way of doing this. However, I am not sure how effective this solution comparing to simple try catch statement.
3. Perform Socket.Send() function inside other thread rather than main thread. The idea is that if Socket.Send() functions fails then the thread used for Socket.send() function will terminate on its own without disturbing the main thread for the application. However, I do not have sufficient knowledge how each thread suppose to interact together. So I can not tell whether this method is better than above two methods.

Can you please suggest any idea or solution for this specific problem? I think that without using Keep alive packet, maintaining the sever operation without crash is quite challenging problem.

Comment: Catch `Exception` instead of `SocketException`, that will ensure the server never crashes.

Comment: Also, ensure the Read loop is protected by try/catch.

Comment: thanks for your comment. What is read loop?

Comment: On the server, are you reading in a loop  or with asynchronous events?

Comment: I use asynchronous events.

Comment: Then forget that, if you read data with BeginRead/EndRead ensure the EndRead is also protected with try/catch, if you use the the modern ReadAsync ensure the ReadAsync call is protected with try/catch and the callback is also protected.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Do you think using another thread might be the better solution than just using try catch statement ?

Comment: No, it's not a good idea, even if you use other thread you need to protect it to be able to clear resources (close socket and destroy any related data), and always is a good idea to inform to the rest of the system when a client has been disconnected what you will not be able without try/catch as the thread will be terminated immediately.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for your help.